# Html::a doesn't link to needed module in Yii2

Tags: html, yii2

I'm trying to link the value to particular action, but somehow it doesn't link me to another module.

Here's the value:

```
'value' = ['module/controller/view', 'id' => $model->id]),
```

Here is the correct link into which I need to be linked:

```
localhost/index.php?r=module/controller/view&id=21
```

Here's the link in which I'm getting linked:

```
localhost/index.php?r=this-module%module%controller%view&id=21
```

As you can see somehow I'm staying in the same module and the link doesn't link me to needed module. Could someone explain me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add slash:

```
['/client/entry/view', ...
```

Without slash it takes it as a subpage of current address.